# =SUM(IIF(Fields!OPTION_CODE.Value="N","0",Fields!COST.Value * Fields!TOTAL_UNITS.Value ) ) only this is working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

i friends i have some problem with this expression. when i am trying to use below its not working plz can any one suggest.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!OPTION_CODE.Value="N","0",Fields!COST.Value * Fields!TOTAL_UNITS.Value ) )
```

is working

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!OPTION_CODE.Value="P","0",Fields!COST.Value * Fields!TOTAL_UNITS.Value ) )
```

is not working

we even try this but its showing error.can u make any changes to work this

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!OPTION_CODE.Value="P","0",IIF(Fields!OPTION_CODE.Value="N","0",Fields!COST.Value * Fields!TOTAL_UNITS.Value ) ))
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?   Are you getting an error?   What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try 0 as integer not as char "0" :

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!OPTION_CODE.Value="P",0,Fields!COST.Value * Fields!TOTAL_UNITS.Value ) )
```